# Inserting rows to Oracle from Ruby

Tags: ruby, oracle, oci8

I have Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.3 installed on a MacMini running Mountain Lion (10.8.3). I am able to create, selected and insert into tables from SQLPlus. However, using Ruby 1.9.3p327 and ruby-oci8-2.1.5, I am able to select but not insert. Insert operation returns 1 (I'm assuming that means success), an immediate select returns the row (is it cached on the client?) but the row is not effectively persisted in the database, and a subsequent select from ruby or SQLPlus returns no rows.

I've checked with Wireshark that there is data going to and coming back from the server box (Windows 7 running Oracle Server Personal Edition 11g Release 2).

Any ideas? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards, Adolfo

Comment: You assume that "1" means "success" but have you verified?

Comment: Do you need to commit the transaction? (Or set autocommit)?

Comment: Actually, matt is correct; I do need to commit the transaction. Thank you both for taking the time to answer.